# trying to validate text input with bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm tryong to validate a simple text input. 
I need to validate the the input is Either Yes or NO.
I'm using the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
IsSSL=$1
if [$IsSSL = "Yes"] || [$IsSSL = "No"];
then 
        echo "correct input"
else
        echo "incorrect input"
fi
```

but I keep getting the following errors:

```
#sh test.sh df
test.sh: line 3: [df: command not found
test.sh: line 3: [df: command not found
incorrect input
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
IsSSL=$1
if [ $IsSSL = "Yes" ] || [ $IsSSL = "No" ];
then 
        echo "correct input"
else
        echo "incorrect input"
fi
```

In bash, you need spaces around [ and ] in if conditions

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
IsSSL=$1
if [ $IsSSL = "Yes" ] || [ $IsSSL = "No" ] ;
then 
        echo "correct input"
else
        echo "incorrect input"
fi
```

You need spaces around the `[`.

Use [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) for stuff like this.

Also you should always quote your variables to avoid complications with special characters in them. So your condition should be 
`if [ "$IsSSL" = "Yes" ] || [ "$IsSSL" = "No" ]` ;